# fs.open fails with file extension - node.js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, fs

I've got the following code:

```
fs.open("uploads/test.txt", "a", "0755", function(err, fd){
  if(err) { console.log(err); } 
  else {
    file.handler = fd; //We store the file handler so we can write to it later
    ...
  }
});
```

The file is created and written to perfectly when I simply have `"uploads/test"`, but when I try to do `"uploads/test.txt"` it breaks. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really silly, but I found what was causing my code to break:

fs.open works as intended. The bug was with my file detection setup using nodemon.

The reason is everytime my app would load it would run the above mentioned code. The code would then write to a new file in my apps `/uploads` directory.  Nodemon would then detect the new file and restart the app thus creating a vicious circle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using

```
  var path = './uploads/test.txt'.
```

Or

```
  var path = __dirname + 'your_path';

fs.open(path, "a", "0755", function(err, fd){
  if(err) { console.log(err); } 
  else {
    file.handler = fd; //We store the file handler so we can write to it later
    ...
  }
});
```